overwrite std::vector<T> with another std::vector<T> efficiently
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility> 

// simple user-defined class
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int val) : value(val) {}

private:
    int value;
};

int main() {
    // Create and initialize sourceVector and destinationVector with MyClass instances
    std::vector<MyClass> sourceVector = {MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(3)};
    std::vector<MyClass> destinationVector = {MyClass(10), MyClass(20), MyClass(30)};

    // Move elements from sourceVector to destinationVector
    destinationVector = std::move(sourceVector);

    // sourceVector.size() = 0 <-- not good

    return 0;
}

Suppose we have std::vector<T> old and std::vector<T> new, which are guaranteed to have the same size or both are uninitialized. The goal is to do an assignment of the form old = new. After this, I do not care what values new has since I will re-compute it. However, what must be guaranteed is that the size of new is not changed. The operation should be very efficient, so I would like to avoid copying (T may be itself a large object.)
Clearly, std::move does not work because it changes the size of the vector.

If old and new are always the same size why would new = std::move(old) change the size of new? That is the most efficient overwrite I can think of. Do you have proof (i.e. profiling) that says otherwise in your code?

Sounds like some obsolete microoptimization. Do you have anything what measures performance? Are you sure you have identify bottleneck properly?

@CoryKramer In the above example after new = std::move(old), we have old.size() = 0 Both vectors should keep their size since the "re-computation" interface relies on that.

If you just want to avoid the movement of your data when large enough of elements are pushed, you can reserve() some space before your algorithm.

BTW, size() and capacity() are not the same. size() will tell you how many elements a vector holds - if you move everything from the old vector, it will hold no elements.

Don't worry about your sizes. Move the one vector into the other; there is nothing more efficient than that, other than using pointers and swapping those. If you already know how many elements you need, or can give an estimate that's not wasting too much memory, reserve() the space you need. This does nothing if the vector already has enough space.

@ChristianStieber How would I do that? In the "re-computation" I do for instance sourceVector[0] = ...results in a segfault after destVector = std::move(sourveVector) ?

As suggested by several comment, isn't your actual need to conserve capacity instead of size (in which case HolyBlackCat answer is perfect)? If so, please edit your question.

@Oersted I actually do not know. As I said, I would like to move source to dest. After this operation, I want to safely write source[2] = ... given that source.size() = 3  before moving.

@Oersted They want to preserve size. And HolyBlackCat's answer does that, given the initial constraint that sourceVector.size() == destinationVector.size().

@Yksisarvinen Indeed, I overlooked the precondition on the sizes.

Move would keep the capacity above initial size. But if you need not source.empty(), then the old dest.swap(source); is your go-to.

std::swap(sourceVector, destinationVector);

or std::ranges::swap(sourceVector, destinationVector); if you feel fancy (which does the same thing).

Any particular reason why, and what the problem was with OP's approach? (Not specifically for me, but for others reading this answer in the future)

Works, but is std::swapinternally not doing a copy of either source or dest before it swaps the elements? This copy would be unnecessary in my case. As the others have pointed out, I have not developed a proper performance measure but I want to make use of the fact that I do not care about the values of source after assignment.

@DanMašek OP themselves said "must be guaranteed ... that the size of new is not changed. ... Clearly, std::move does not work because it changes the size of the vector."

@DanMašek   The OP's approach is essentially destinationVector = std::move(sourceVector) which doesn't guarantee that sourceVector.size() is unchanged - even if, before-hand, sourceVector and destinationVector have the same size.   Apart from leaving sourceVector is a state in which it may be safely destructed, that approach provides almost no guarantee about the state of sourceVector.

@Mathieu swap will move when possible (IIRC, when move-assignment is available.) That is, swap(x, y) becomes T a = std::move(x); x = std::move(y); y = std::move(a);, which basically just rearranges some pointers.

@Mathieu When in doubt : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap Exchanges the contents and capacity of the container with those of other. Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements. So I agree with moldbnilo... can't be more efficient than this

@Peter Ya, I know, I was hoping to see that in the answer. And it makes sense for the moved-from vector to be empty, since otherwise you'd be paying for a (potentially huge) allocation of something that you made no indication you'd need (and in most cases won't).
